# Is there light where there is no electromagnetic field?

Tags: waves

If light is oscillation in the electromagnetic field, then is there light where there is no electromagnetic field? Are there places without any electromagnetic fields?

Comment: Try looking Faraday cage for places with no EM fields. And yes, no EM field would mean no light.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are misunderstanding.

Light is not oscillation in electromagnetic field. It is not like a particle oscillating in a field. It is the electromagnetic wave itself.
By propagation of light, we mean the energy that moves in a sinusoidal wave, comprising of a magnetic field, and an electric field.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Please correct me if my answer is wrong or insufficient.